# Keith Wood's jQuery SVG plugin does not display Y axis properly

Tags: jquery-plugins, svg

I set my Y axis max as 1, min as 0 and tick as 0.1. The graph displays as 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000004, 0.4 etc. What I mean here is that it does not display 0.3 properly and also some other values in a the similar style. But once I set the tick to more than 0.2, it will display everything properly. So anyone else have experienced the same problem or just myself doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an extremely common problem across all of computing. For JavaScript, use `toFixed(1)` to format your floating point number as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out myself.

In the jquery.svggraph.js file which comes with the plugin, line 493, it adds the tick value to the previous value, so in my case the previous value was 0.2 when it adds 0.1 to it, the result becomes 0.3000000004. I don't know why it does that, maybe it stores the value as float number. What I did to solve this is to add major = Math.round( major * 100 ) / 100 under line 498. Hope this might help someone else who had same problem as I did.